# Customize UITabBar with Images and Transparency

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

For iOS 4, how can I customize the UITabBar to build something like this??

http://prntscr.com/7vuvj

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's mostly some fancy UI images, but as for the raised center tab, the [RaisedCenterTabBar](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar) project handles that quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I did a tutorial recently to show you how to create your own side tab bar that can be used to achieve this effect [here](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=777) using a custom segue. It is relatively straight forward and makes this type of effect really easy to achieve. Hope this helps let me know how you get on.

Edit: Here is the [demo code](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/DemoTabBar4.0.zip) for the tutorial done for iOS 4.0 hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! But I want it for iOS4, yours should work on iOS 5 only.

Comment: Yes true but the principle is the same. You can use buttons to load up xibs and replace the placeholder view with the view in your placeholder xib. If you need an example I could try and put one together for you if you don't understand what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, pls give me an example if you could, thanks!!

Comment: Let me know how you get on with the demo code, I am in the process of finishing a youtube video for this very tutorial (all be it iOS 5.0). Thanks

Comment: Works great! Is it possible to add transitions like cross dissolve to the changing of views?